# What is the difference between flutter build bundle and appbundle in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-app-bundle, flutter-build

I find little to no information on what's the difference between these two

```
flutter build bundle
```

```
flutter build appbundle
```

When should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
flutter build appbundle
```

builds the 'app bundle' that is uploaded to the Google Play store. The app bundle is basically a bundle of `apk` files. When a user installs your app, Google Play will serve the optimal `apk` to the device. The app bundle is compressed into a `aab` file (Android app bundle).

```
flutter build bundle
```

builds a special 'app bundle' archive from the list of assets in your `pubspec.yaml` that your app can read from at runtime. The builder places this in the `flutter_assets` folder in the `build` directory.

So basically they build different stuff. `flutter build appbundle` is pretty much unavoidable if you're building an app for release on the Play Store.

However, I have never needed to use `flutter build bundle`. I have never needed to build an individual assets folder as it's incorporated within an `appbundle` build.

Comment: Thank you. We were using `flutter build bundle` in our CI environment and I couldn't figure our why. To me it makes sense to build the actual app in CI and not just the asset directory (which takes about 30 seconds compared to 4 minutes).  Thank you for confirming my suspicions about this confusing and undocumented topic!

Comment: No probs. And thanks for replying (so many people don't bother)